# Date passed as argument to SQL Server Stored Procedure - called from pyodbc script

Tags: python, pyodbc

Is there something that happens to the date formatting when passing a date as an argument to a SQL server stored procedure?

I have a python script that is on Windows Server 2012 that calls a stored procedure using pyodbc.

This works without a problem for some dates (e.g. '2020-01-30') but not for other dates (e.g. '2020-01-31').  If the stored procedure is called from SQL Server Management Studio with one of the dates that DOES NOT work from the Python script (e.g. '2020-01-31') it works without a problem.

Comment: What happens with these "troublesome" dates? Do you get an error - if so: **what** error?

Comment: No error message - the SP just does not trigger the commands in it (to create records and send emails)

Answer (score 0):

What **datatype** is the parameter? The `DATETIME` datatype is known to be rather picky about what string literals it can properly interpret as valid dates.

The general consensus is that you should either use other datatypes (e.g. `DATE`, if you only need the date - no time portion) - or if that's not feasible, then use the **ISO-8601** formatting for the date:

```
20200131
YYYYMMDD
```

without any dashes or anything.

Comment: The **datetype** is date.  There is no requirement for the time portion to be passed to the stored procedure.  It does have dashes in it YYYY-MM-DD.  I do not think that it is the dashes that are causing the issue, otherwise, why would 2020-01-30 work?